# Understanding Chemical Potential (Li-ion)

Tags: electrochemistry, bond, reduction-potential

Can anyone help me to understand what the "Chemical Potential" is? I can see that in batteries the electrical energy is stored as "chemical potential", according to [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1369702115003181):

> Li-ion batteries, Na-ion batteries, and Mg-ion batteries, reversibly
> convert between electrical and chemical energy via redox reactions,
> thus storing the energy as chemical potential in their electrodes.

So what is chemical potential? According to Wikipedia, it is defined as:

> In thermodynamics, chemical potential, also known as partial molar
> free energy, is a form of potential energy that can be absorbed or
> released during a chemical reaction or phase transition

Which is quite straight forward, in a way. However, it doesn't really make me understanding it entirely, therefore I would like to ask if there is anyone that can help me understand this. I'm always trying to use analogies and therefore I would like to ask the following question:

> Can the chemical potential be seen like the latent heat, where the
> energy is stored as bonds and, in order to break the bonds, one needs
> to add extra energy.

Or is it more complex than this? Please see below a sketch with what I imagine happens inside. Did I understand it right?

[image]

It's hard for me to understand what keeps the energy there. Any help counts!

Thank you!

Comment: You're talking about two very different things, thermodynamic potential and electrode potential.

Comment: Can you please explain which is which?

Comment: Well, you should be able to guess... or simply google it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrode_potential